# Can one conditionally call static method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following JS firebase function for querying:

```
return this.store
  .collection(collection, ref =>
    ref
      .where(query.field, query.operation, query.searchKey)
      .orderBy(orderBy.key, orderBy.direction)
      .orderBy(orderBySecond.key, orderBySecond.direction)
      .limit(limit.limit)
```

However, I don't always have limit or second order by or even a where clause. Currently, I have many `if` statements to check if these parameters exists (`query`, `orderBy`, etc.) and I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

To add more information, currently my code is something like that (please note that it still doesn't cover all possible variants):

```
public runQuery(
collection: string,
query: FirestoreQuery,
orderBy?: FirestoreOrderBy,
limit?: FirestoreLimit,
orderBySecond?: FirestoreOrderBy
  ): Observable<any> {
    if (orderBy) {
      if (limit) {
        if (orderBySecond) {
          return this.store
            .collection(collection, ref =>
              ref
                .where(query.field, query.operation, query.searchKey)
                .orderBy(orderBy.key, orderBy.direction)
                .orderBy(orderBySecond.key, orderBySecond.direction)
                .limit(limit.limit)
            )
            .valueChanges();
        } else {
          return this.store
            .collection(collection, ref =>
              ref
                .where(query.field, query.operation, query.searchKey)
                .orderBy(orderBy.key, orderBy.direction)
                .limit(limit.limit)
            )
            .valueChanges();
        }
      } else {
        return this.store
          .collection(collection, ref =>
            ref
              .where(query.field, query.operation, query.searchKey)
              .orderBy(orderBy.key, orderBy.direction)
          )
          .valueChanges();
      }
    } else {
      return this.store
        .collection(collection, ref => ref.where(query.field, query.operation, query.searchKey))
        .valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Most ORMs these days provide methods that return `this` as their return-value, which is what allows the various method-calls to be "chained" in this way.  You can stretch these out to multiple statements, e.g.  `if (some_condition) ref = ref.orderBy(...);`  Then, use the `ref` variable as it finally turned out.